# Значение слова "эпохалка"

Tags: лексика

Сегодня в фейсбуке в комментариях встретил слово эпохалка. Полез в интернет искать. На просторах интернета оно встречается, а вот что означает - не написано. Может, кому-н. известно, что оно означает?

Comment: Ужасный нео-кошмаризм.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Словечко встретилось вот в этом немецко-русском [**словаре**](https://umgangssprachlichen.academic.ru/2733/epochal):
﻿
**epochal**
*ирон. преувелич.* "эпохальный", "сенсационный".
**epochales** Werk *ирон.* о незначительном произведении: эпохалка, нетленка.

Думаю, что слово можно считать жаргонизмом (или отнести к молодёжному сленгу).
Процесс возникновения-образования, возможно, таков (во всяком случае, очень похож):
чрезвычайка – чрезвычайное происшествие, нетленка – от нетленное произведение, минималка – минимальная зарплата, эпохалка – эпохальное произведение.

*Фильм о простом сталеваре, его подруге и добром Сталине, который с ними беседует на протяжении всего фильма: то в кабинете, то в саду, где мичуринец Сталин сажает дерево, то в поверженном Берлине. Я поначалу думал – эпохалка.*
А. Шервуд. Байки старого еврея